# checkcolumn validation

Tags: extjs4.1

I have a checkcolumn (called 'Leader') and when the user clicks th 'Create Project' button, I want there to be an alert message displayed if no checkboxes in the checkcolumn are checked (i.e. if the user does not select a checkbox). Right now I have the following code which creates an array (called 'data') of all the 'Leader' checkcolumn values of each record. However I do not know how to display an alert if all the values (in 'data') are false (i.e. no checkbox is checked). Here is my code:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Create Project',
    id: 'createprojectbutton',
    handler: function (){
     var form = this.up('form').getForm();
     var data = [];
     teststore.each(function(rec){
      data.push(rec.get('Leader'));
     });  
  }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Create Project',
    id: 'createprojectbutton',
    handler: function (){

        var iHasLeader = false;
        teststore.each(function(rec){
            // Assuming the leader field is boolean, any leader that is true
            // will render iHasLeader as true.
            iHasLeader = iHasLeader || rec.get('Leader');
        });  
        if ( !iHasLeader )
            alert( 'No leader');
    }
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. But I do not understand what is happening in the following line of code: iHasLeader = iHasLeader || rec.get('Leader');
Could you perhaps explain? Thanks,

Comment: It simply means that `iHasLeader` is equal to itself OR the rec boolean field saying if there's a leader. With OR, if either is true the result will be true. So any record that has `Leader` true will set `iHasLeader` as true, and it will stay that why thereafter since now `iHasLeader` is true - doesn't matter what is the value in the rec. Does this make sense?